# In which format (format, not cypher algo.) does Electrum encrypt its files?

Tags: electrum, encryption

Electrum wallet encrypts its files using the AES-256-CBC algorithm, but in which format does it encrypt files? (I mean, what headers, vectors, checksums etc. it adds and where?)

By format I mean OpenPGP, S/MIME etc.